# Knockout subscribe/event type system without observable?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to make use of the subscribe() function of knockout js to manually trigger an event at a certain point.

I could make an observable() and everytime put a GUID in there to trigger the scubscribe.

Is there a cleaner way within Knockout js to have a typical event-like structure?

**Edit**
Ok, apparently I can use observable.valueHasMutated() - might already a a bit cleaner that using a GUID.

**Example**

This is the behaviour that I'm looking for:

```
function Car()
{
    var self = this;

    self.onOpenDoor = ko.observable();

    self.openDoor = function()
    {
        // using an observable / valueHasMutated for this feels a bit hacky
        // is there an other way to use the underlying subscribe() system?
        self.onOpenDoor.valueHasMutated();
    }
}


var car = new Car();

// multiple subscribers
car.onOpenDoor.subscribe(function()
{
    console.log('Do something');
})
car.o**nOpenDoor.subscribe(function()
{
    console.log('Do something else');
})

car.openDoor();
```

*I am aware this is not the default 'knockout' way to do stuff - that is not what this question is about.*

**Update**

After @RoyJ's reference to Niemeyer's blog I went for this solution:

```
function Car()
{
    var self = this;

    self.onOpenDoor = new ko.subscribable();

    self.openDoor = function()
    {
        self.onOpenDoor.notifySubscribers();
    }
}
```

Comment: well are you looking to attach a event to non-observable and looking to trigger it ?

Comment: Uhm. Yeah in a way. I'm looking for a simple way event/subscriber pattern, and because I already use knockout I'd like to keep the same framwork / syntax.

Comment: You could make it a counter, rather than using a GUID. It would track the number of times your event was triggered.
`triggerCount(triggerCount() + 1)`

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking. If you're having trouble with a specific implementation, you should probably post a minimal repro of your situation and be specific about the issue. If you're actually asking if / how you could use KnockoutJS as a message bus, the question is rather broad (and currently a bit unclear to me too).

Comment: @DirkBoer you applying valueHasMutated on observable i.e this `self.onOpenDoor.valueHasMutated();` which is not at all needed (internally it trigger valueHasMutated  when change happens in observable) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** If you're just looking for clarity, you *can* use `notifySubscribers` instead of `valueHasMutated`. You might want to take a look at the base type of observables, [ko.subscribable](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/using-ko-native-pubsub.html).

I would do it like this:

```
var vm = {
    ///...definitions...
    openCount: ko.observable(0),
    openDoor: function () {
        vm.openCount(vm.openCount()+1);
    }
};

vm.openCount.subscribe(function () {
    ///...do something
});

vm.openCount.subscribe(function () {
    ///...do something else
});

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/uoqdfhdb/2/

Comment: Hi Roy, thanks the notifySubscribers and the blog that you posted from Niemeyer is exactly what I meant! Just a question: why do you prefer the solution you posted here above? In a way it has more 'syntactic fluff' around it, and I prefer that the notifysubscribers solution shows more meaning. What are your thoughts?

Comment: It just makes sense to me to keep track of how many times I've done something and do something every time that changes. I don't usually think in the pub/sub model.

Comment: @RoyJ doing  a subscribe to same observable twice . are you sure you need that . #GiveItasecondTought

Comment: well not in this very specific case - it's just an example :) it's used for decoupling my classes

Comment: @supercool The two subscribes would (presumably) be in different, unrelated places in the code.